# Camel guaranteed message order for different routes

Tags: java, spring, web-services, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel 2.10.0 with spring-ws component to route some (20+) WS/SOAP operations.
The sample code looks like:

```
from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://my/name/space}myOperation1?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://my/name/space}myOperation2?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
from("spring-ws:rootqname:{http://my/name/space}myOperation3?endpointMapping=#endpointMapping")
```

Operations normally access several DB and could last up to couple of seconds

It works perfectly, but now I have a new requirement: 3 of the operations must be synchronized.

For example: if client1 calls operation1 1ms before client2 calling operation1, the client1’s call must be finished before starting client2’s one.

Same is valid for 1 client calling 2 different operations.

For example: if client1 calls operation1 1ms before calling operation2, the operation1’s call must be finished before starting operation2’s one. Clients call the WS asynchronously and this cannot be changed

The application is running with WebLogic 10.3.5.

Reducing the container threads to 1 only would affect all operations, thus I was thinking about adding of some custom queue (JMS style) only to these 3 operations.

Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Have a look at Apache Kafka; it's not a full-blown JMS but has some interesting features like being able to process old messages again.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

It looks all the calling some be put into the queue first, then we can decide which one should be invoked then.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ is easy to setup and would work with Camel very well.

You need to route the request to JMS queue first, the queue itself is the transaction break point, then you consume JMS messages sequentially. You have much more control of the threading and message consuming by using the message pattern